# How to center a navigation bar on a virtual horse game

Tags: html, css, encoding

i play a horse game called Horseland. We have our own web pages on there and the pages have CSS and HTML sections to put layouts and such. I am new to coding layouts and had a very simple question.

How do i center the navigation bar at the very top of the page? I've seen other people do it but they refuse to tell me how for what ever unexplained reason. If you could help that would be great I can even attach a photo to explain what i mean.

[image: Navigation Bar link]

That is to show you what bar i am talking about and here is a full page view of the same bar!

[image: Link]

Thank you very much and all suggestions would be very helpful!

Comment: Hi Welcome to SO.  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Answer (score -1):

You could wrap it up in an div, and set the div in css to
margin: auto

Comment: unless this wrapper div is given a width, then this will not work as the wrapper will be 100%